# multi subject blog module

Tags: drupal, blogs, drupal-modules

I'm building a website in drupal and I need a multi-subjects blog because the core multi-user module is not enough (from what I know). So, my questions is, there is a module for multi-subject blog or a way to expand the core blog module?

thanks you for all of your help, barak.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming D7:

The simplest way may be to utilize Taxonomy. You could create a vocab of  subjects, then add a term reference field to the blog entry content type. If you want a drop down list of already-entered categories/subjects then use the "Select list" widget. Autocomplete is there for  tagging.